# invoking batch script/Java code from Oracle database

Tags: java, oracle, batch-file, shell

I have a requirment, of invoking a Java file from Oracle database. In my project, whole of my business logic is in database, but there is a requirement of invoking a third party system (SOAP / RMI call) from my application.

Now for this i need to invoke atleast a Java Code or a batch script file (depending on Windows(.bat) Or Linux(.sh)).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this page: http://www.cs.umbc.edu/portal/help/oracle8/java.815/a64686/04_call2.htm

You can can Java-Code from your PL/SQL.

Comment: but with this case, where to put the java file, or the class file.

Comment: Look at this document: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31225/chfive.htm#BABGCGBG

Answer (score 1):

[Web-service call outs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31225/chtwelve.htm#CBBEFCHI) can be done from the Oracle Database. I'm not sure why you need to use Java for this as PL/SQL also allows for outbound calls using UTL_DBWS.

If you do not intend to use JPublisher, or you have a very simple web-service to consume, then you can use [UTL_HTTP](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/u_http.htm#CHDIAFFA) itself, or the appropriate class in Java - [HttpURLConnection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html). However, I've never seen any case where a JAX-RPC library or any other web-service library was loaded into the database using *loadjava*, and used to make web-service calls; it ought to be possible do so, as long as the library is very light (in not depending on other libraries that cannot be loaded or used in the database), and requires permissions only to connect out from the database.

**Related question**

- [Access Web service from Oracle stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299002/access-web-service-from-oracle-stored-procedure)