# PL/SQL Procedure to call a Restful Web Service and update DB table

Tags: oracle, rest, stored-procedures, plsql

I need a PL/SQL block that will call a restful web service. 
For example

```
http://localhost:8080/SampleApp/fetchEmployeeData
```

This Procedure will be scheduled to run every 5 minutes, and I want to call another web service every time this PL/SQL block runs and pass the job running time to that web service.

I can't find any example to call a restful web service on net. 
This example is not working for me.
[Access Web service from Oracle stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299002/access-web-service-from-oracle-stored-procedure)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the code you're running and what, specifically, is "not working".  Are you getting an error?

Comment: I think because provided example applies for SOAP calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Oracle way is using [Oracle REST Data Services](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/rest-data-services/overview/index.html)

Check **Accessing the RESTful Services from a Third Party Application** chapter.